# Is there a Hotkey to pin / auto hide a panel like Solution Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, hotkeys

Is there a Hotkey to pin / auto hide a panel like Solution Explorer?

It would be a good combinations with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> which focus Solution Explorer.

Comment: How is this related to ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can close any panel using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>. So hit the key combination with the focus on the solution explorer and it will close. You can then use the shortcut that you mentioned to open the solution explorer again.

If you'd rather auto-hide and dock the panel instead of closing it, you can define shortcuts for `Window.AutoHide` and `Window.Dock`.

For Example:

`Window.AutoHide (`<kbd>Shift</kbd>`+`<kbd>Space</kbd>`(Global))`

`Window.Dock (`<kbd>Shift</kbd>`+`<kbd>Alt</kbd>`+`<kbd>Space</kbd>`(Global))`

Comment: This shortcut unfortunately does not work if the panel already is docked. The only somewhat solution I have found for this is menu:Window->Auto hide all windows as presented in [MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/06/18/auto-hide-all-tool-windows/).

Comment: `Let's agree` to use `Ctrl+P,Ctrl+D` to `dock` the current panel and `Ctrl+P,Ctrl+H` to `hide` the current panel. Just as a convention.

Answer (score 5):

At least in Visual studio 2015 and 2017 there is a command `Window.AutoHide` that does the trick *for already docked panels*. It is the same as `menu:Window->Auto hide all` and it autohides all panels in the same stack. Either use standard menu command <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> respective <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> or give it a shortcut of its own.

Comment: Auto-hide is nice, yes. If only there was also a way to bring it back to the former state...

Comment: Is there a way to bind Auto-hide and Dock to a single button? So you can toggle it. In rider or other JetBrains IDEs it's very easy to achieve this